# Maui Page Navigation to a tabbedView

Tags: .net, maui

I've got a Disclaimer Page, then another wizard like page before granting the user access to my main application.

The navigation between the Disclaimer and the wizards are done, working via the Shell.Navigate functions. I can go back and forth and it works a dream.

Now, I've gone some googling and found some stackoverflow things but none that go into much detail! I'm a newbie when it comes to MAUI.

Here's what I've got so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MonkeyFinder.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:TermsOfServiceViewModel"
             x:Class="MonkeyFinder.View.TermsOfServicePage"
             Title="TermsOfServicePage">

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*" 
        ColumnSpacing="5" 
        RowDefinitions="*"
        RowSpacing="0">

        <ScrollView Margin="10">
            <Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porttitor euismod arcu nec accumsan. Nulla purus diam, pharetra eget nisi sed, lobortis convallis arcu. Nullam imperdiet varius cursus. Maecenas viverra est id ex dignissim viverra consequat eget nulla. Maecenas hendrerit metus vel ipsum rutrum convallis. Curabitur viverra semper diam, vitae venenatis ex sollicitudin in. Fusce rutrum metus viverra, ultrices risus vel, facilisis lorem. Etiam quis urna diam. Praesent et euismod ante."
               />
        </ScrollView>

        <Button Text="Find Services" Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
         Command="{Binding ShowServiceSearchCommand}"
         Grid.Row="1" Margin="8"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The viewmodel for the page above

```
 public partial class TermsOfServiceViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     [RelayCommand]
     async Task ShowServiceSearch()
     {
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ServiceSearchPage)}", true, new Dictionary<string, object>
         {
         });
     }
 }
```

This illustates how I'm doing the navigation between pages. Like I said works well.

Now, my main page looks like this

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           >
    <TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage Title="{Binding Name}"
                         IconImageSource="monkeyicon.png">
                <StackLayout Padding="5, 25">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           WidthRequest="200"
                           HeightRequest="200" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="50, 10">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="Family: "
                                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Family}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                       
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
</TabbedPage>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class ResultsPage : TabbedPage
{
    public ResultsPage()
    {
       
    }
}
```

Notice I don't have an initialise Method...

And I can't navigate to it since I get the following error:

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x7f080147 (com.companyname.monkeyfinder:id/navigationlayout_toptabs) for fragment ViewFragment{eb4c4b8} (9313dd25-30ff-4d1e-af0d-974ab44b35ae id=0x7f080147)'

Am I using the wrong component?

Comment: Can you share how you're registering the routes?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean this error occur when you navigation to the TabbedPage from a shell page?  And why don't have an initialise Method in TabbedPage?

Comment: You could try setting this ```Application.Current.MainPage = new ResultsPage();``` when you want to navigate to your main page.